# First Rule not appending correctly on CSS JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript

This Function lets you add CSS rules and it puts the rules on your stylesheet, but it has an appending problem.  First here is the code then explanation that follows.

```
var addCSSRule = function(sheet, selector, rules){
//Backward searching of the selector matching cssRules
   var index=sheet.cssRules.length - 1;
   for(var i=index; i>0; i--){
     var current_style = sheet.cssRules[i];
     if(current_style.selectorText === selector){
       //Append the new rules to the current content of the cssRule;
       rules=current_style.style.cssText + rules;
       sheet.deleteRule(i);
       index=i;
     }
   }
   if(sheet.insertRule){
     sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}", index);
   }
   else{
     sheet.addRule(selector, rules, index);
   }
   return sheet.cssRules[index].css;
   }

addCSSRule(myStyleSheet, "#container", "height: 300px;");
addCSSRule(myStyleSheet, "#container", "width: 300px;");
addCSSRule(myStyleSheet, "#container", "border: 2px solid blue;");
addCSSRule(myStyleSheet, "#container", "background-color: red;");
```

Well to be fair, I didn't come up with this.  I found this on a website http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets.  However there is a problem with it.  The rules append like they should, except for the first rule, well sort of.  It appends okay, that is to say, the rule is recognized, but whenever you inspect element, its not with all the other rules.  See picture below.  Basically the first rule isn't appending right, like all the others.

[image: notice append problem]

Comment: I think this might simply be due to the fact that the for loop `for(var i=index; i>0; i--)` only runs while `i` is greater than zero, whereas it should run as long as `i` is greater-equal zero.

Comment: Interesting observation.  Yes, I suppose that does make alot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's late, so instead of figuring out what's wrong with your function I've made you a new one, here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w4ckvde3/), it works just the same.

### JavaScript

```
function setRule(sheet,selector,rules){
    var cssrules = sheet.cssRules;
    for( var i = 0 , l = cssrules.length ; i < l ; i ++ ){
        var cssrule = cssrules[i];
        var cssselector = cssrule.selectorText;
        if( cssselector == selector ){
            var rules = rules.split(";");
            for( var j = 0 , rl = rules.length ; j < rl ; j ++ ){
                var rule = rules[j];
                var parts = rule.split(":");
                var property = parts[0];
                var value = parts[1];
                cssrule.style[property] = value;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}",cssrules.length);
}
```

### Usage

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
setRule(sheet,"div","background:red;width:200px;height:200px;");
```

As you can see it functions like the other one, in the demo there is actually a `setTimeout` call to demonstrate the ability to change the rule after inserting it.

Hope it helps, if you still want me to fix the other function, tell me and I'll do it in the morning, good night!

**Update:** Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v65j7ytk/) with your example, just in case :)

Comment: Wow Rou, works great.  This is definetely something I can study and learn from.